# Only Half of CoRoutine Being called

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have written code with a singleton pattern made for saving the top score of my player. It works fine when running through the first iteration. But when I go into different scenes and come back to the 'game' scene, only the first half of the while loop I wrote activates. Here is my script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ScoreSaver : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static ScoreSaver score;
    private int scoreSpeed = 1;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public static int topScore;
    public int currentScore = 0;


    void Awake()
    {
       if (score == null)
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            score = this;
        }
       else if (score != this)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        StartCoroutine(ScoreCounter());

    }



    IEnumerator ScoreCounter()
    {
        while (SceneManager.GetActiveScene() == SceneManager.GetSceneByName("game")) 
        {
            Debug.Log("New Score Counter while loop is called");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);
            Debug.Log("New Score Counter seconds have been waited");
            currentScore += scoreSpeed;
            Debug.Log("New Score Counter Score: " + currentScore);
        }
        Debug.Log("New Score Counter IEnumerator is called");
        if (currentScore > topScore)
        {
            topScore = currentScore;
            Debug.Log("New Score Counter Top Score: " + currentScore);
        }
        currentScore = 0;
        Debug.Log("New Score Counter Current Score post Rest: " + currentScore);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

It calls up to the "yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);" line, but does not call past it. It also doesn't run the rest of the function until the scene ends. So I really have no idea what is going on. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up `DontDestroyOnload` and the `Singleton` pattern. Separate them into their own different code events. Like this:

```
void Awake()
{
    // First do the DontDestroyOnLoad
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    
    // Now do the singleton pattern
    if (score == null)
    {
        score = this;
    }
    else if (score != this)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

void Start() {
    // Do your code reoutine in start not awake 
    StartCoroutine(ScoreCounter());
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! While this didn't solve my answer completely, it led me to find the answer myself, which I couldn't have done without your advice.